# Add Elementary OS Stack Exchange to the off topic banner

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-declined, close-reasons

This banner:

[image]

could now include the [Elementary OS](http://elementaryos.stackexchange.com) site.

Comment: How many "Elementary OS" questions do we get? IMO the paragraph should not grow any more.

Comment: @guntbert enough that i think people should be redirected to get help..

Comment: I actually agree. There may not be many questions, but there are enough that I see them pretty often. @guntbert

Comment: @guntbert bearing in mind most are deleted, 200+ is a fair number... http://askubuntu.com/search?tab=newest&q=elementary%20os%20is%3aq

Comment: I think "questions about other Linux distributions" sufficiently explains it and subtly hints to the OP of a closed question that they came to the wrong neighbourhood :) No need to overindulge in listing which distros are off-topic. We could however have a link to a list of the supported releases :)

Answer (score 8):

**Note:** *This answer now also exists as [separate feature request](http://meta.askubuntu.com/q/14982/367990) here on meta.askubuntu.com.

Further updates and discussion should take place over there.

If you like this answer, please make sure you also upvote the linked question. Thanks!*

## I have a completely different suggestion.

What about rewording the banner to something like

> This is not about Ubuntu.
>
> Please visit our [off-topic compass] to find out on which partner site in the Stack Exchange network your problem might fit best.

And then create a nice community-wiki site here on *meta.askubuntu.com* which looks like this:

> ### Q: My question was marked as off-topic, where should I ask it instead?
>
> You posted a question here and excitedly waited for an answer, but received a close banner like this?
>
> [image: example image]
>
> Read through the answers below to find out where your question would fit best!

---

> ### A: Unix & Linux
>
> Every question about any UNIX or Linux based system is allowed here.
> However, if you use for example Ubuntu, ElementaryOS, OSX or Android, there are specialized sites for them, where you can get more specific answers.

---

> ### A: Stack Overflow
>
> All general programming questions should be asked here.
> If you have working code and just look for optimizations, you're better of at Code Review though.

---

> ### A: Super User
>
> This is the most general site all about computers and related stuff. Every operating system is welcome, and so are hardware problems.

---

... and so on, one answer for each possibly related site.

Comment: Should I maybe convert this answer into a new feature request question?

Comment: yes 100% please!

Comment: This answer now exists as separate feature request: http://meta.askubuntu.com/q/14982/367990

Answer (score 4):

The off-topic banner isn't meant to be all encompassing. That would be impossible to maintain and extremely messy. It covers the basic and most common occurrences, it's up to the user to figure the rest out. That's not our job. What do you propose we do if/when sites specific to Mint, Kali, or [insert other Ubuntu based distribution here] launch?

As it is we only have 28 characters remaining in the existing reason anyway, so we couldn't add it even if we wanted to.

Comment: What do you think about my proposal below? That way we could both save space in the banner and create a very user friendly and complete list of all possibly related sister sites and a short summary of their scopes. The only way to add more user friendliness in my opinion would be to implement automatic migration (which wouldn't work well...).

Answer (score 2):

## No.

Sorry, the message is space limited and we need to mention Windows, Mac and just don't have the room (or in my case, inclination) to list every non-Ubuntu distribution directly.

Comment: We just don't get as many Mac questions as we get eOS ones, and Mac questions are also covered by U&L. Just nuke Ask Different and replace it with eOS.

Comment: @muru And what do you propose when Mint, Kali, bodhi, zorin, etc all get their own site?

Comment: @Seth give an ETA on that and I will come up with a proposal in T - 6months.

Comment: Question: so if someone came up with a sentence stating the same but with less words it would be ok? >:-D

Comment: What do you think about my proposal above? That way we could both save space in the banner and create a very user friendly and complete list of all possibly related sister sites and a short summary of their scopes. The only way to add more user friendliness in my opinion would be to implement automatic migration (which wouldn't work well...).